# Skip the last page - Smartform

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I have a Smartform with 2 pages:

```
FIRST > NEXT
NEXT > NEXT.
```

I want to skip the last page according to a condition. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the last page context into a subform (folder element). The subform must be shown if the condition is true.

Comment: I asked it for Smartform :)

Comment: This is for smartforms. You can do next. Put all your smartforms elements on the same page. So, you will have only one page in your smartform structure. Then create a folder (I called it 'subform' in my post above) in your smartform and move all elements from your last page to the folder. Put a command "Go to new page" in the beginining of the folder. The folder can be created via conext menu: Create->folder. You will be able to apply the output conditions (Conditions tab) to the folder and hide/show your last page content.

Comment: The page elements have no options like hide upon a condition. So, you should go via folders with conditions.